Is there a way to avoid dark areas inside objects when baking light? (Unity light baking)
I have a drawer. Is there a way to bake the light so that when it is pulled out, it lights up inside? Is it possible to make the casing not only receive the rays but also simultaneously let them pass through?


light settings:




what are the light settings?

Lightmap baking is for static objects, which this drawer evidently is not.

Added screenshots
